# VueJS v-for An Array of Key:Values From Store Using a Method

Tags: vuejs2, store, vuex, v-for

**How can I use `v-for` to get an array of key:values from a store using a method?**

[The CodePen is available here](https://codepen.io/CelticParser/pen/aMEqax)

I appreciate any help.

P.S. *I've been on SO for 10yrs and someone/somehow deleted my account. So, I'm starting an*ew.

Comment: Can you share sample Input/Output you expected here sharing codes? What should `globalHours ()` return? And why this empty for loop in template `v-for=""` ?

Comment: Uh..., returns the `$store.state.globalHrsRef.data` key:value(s) LOL

Comment: for `item[0]` what exactly should return by `globalHours ()`?

Comment: Your LinkedIn profile says "you worked on Vuex..."? Look at the store's state - lines 6 thru 11

Comment: yes, the `globalHourse()` already returning values = `[381, 293.3, 168.4, 110.8, 57.7, 132.9]` always so that I'm confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `v-for="(item, index) in array"` will extract the values from the index.

Update: `globalHours()[index]` replaces `globalHours()`